# ip address to NSAP ID

Tags: perl, ip, trim

can anyone help me come up with a perl script or javascript that would translate an IP address to an NSAP ID? i have a form for users to fill out and with the ip address and would like to auto populate the NSAP portion.

These are some requirements

Example: 
192.168.1.1

pad  each octet to 3 characters
192.168.001.001

change to groups of 4
1921.6800.1001

add .00 to the end
1921.6800.1001.00

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tryed so far. As this question stand it pretty mutch ask "please give me code". As it stand now it will probably be closed. Try to work the process in your language and than translate that to code. Split ip on the dot, pad with leading 0 if each part are less than 3 caracters, add the dot, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSAP ID or a End System ID is a 6 byte field usually represented in dot-decimal notation as `xxxx.xxxx.xxxx`. The two zeros you add at the end are NSAP Selector (NSEL) which identifies a network service user which in your case is network entity title (NET) or a network layer of a system itself. So what you are making technically is not NSAP ID but a last part of a NSAP address.

Below is a perl script that takes IP address (`$ip`) and does the stuff you explained in your question and prints it.

```
my $tmp = "";
foreach my $part (split('\.', $ip)){
  $tmp = $tmp . sprintf("%03s", $part);
}
$tmp =~ s/(.{4})/$1./g;
print $tmp . "00";
```

If you are going to use this on a website in a form maybe it's easier to write it in javascript so you can display it immediately to the user.

Comment: thanks for writing this, i agree, i think it will be better with JS.